# How to draw and format this image (equilateral triangles) in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm writing up a problem set and thought it would be cool to figure out how to do this in TikZ for a nice look rather than just insert the image. I would also like to format it in the center of my page. If anyone could help, that would be great!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

No need to call the `calc` library for this, just put some nice coordinates while you draw your triangles.

[image: different triangular pieces]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\def\r{3} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) --++ (0:\r) coordinate[pos=1/3] (a) coordinate[pos=2/3] (b) --++ (120:\r) coordinate[pos=1/3] (c) -- cycle coordinate[pos=2/3] (e);
        \draw (e) -- (c) coordinate[pos=0.5] (d) -- (b) -- (d) -- (a) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \qquad
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) --++ (0:\r) coordinate[pos=0.5] (a) --++ (120:\r) coordinate[pos=0.5] (b) -- cycle coordinate[pos=0.5] (c);
        \draw (a) -- (b) coordinate[pos=0.5] (d) -- (c) coordinate[pos=0.5] (e) -- cycle coordinate[pos=0.5] (f);
        \draw (d) -- (e) -- (f) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \qquad
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) --++ (0:\r) coordinate[pos=0.25] (a) coordinate[pos=0.5] (b) coordinate[pos=0.75] (c) --++ (120:\r) coordinate[pos=0.25] (d) -- cycle coordinate[pos=0.75] (g);
        \draw (g) -- (d) coordinate[pos=1/3] (f) coordinate[pos=2/3] (e) -- (c) -- (e) -- (b) -- (f) -- (a) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much this is really great! What does the \def\r{3} do? why not just use 3 instead of \r?

Comment: Actually, this does give errors when I try to run it:
<to be read again> 
                   =
l.196         \draw (0,0) --++ (0:\r)
                                      coordinate[pos=1/3] (a) coordinate[pos...
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfmath@dimen@ ...men@@ #1=0.0pt\relax \pgfmath@

^^^ example of one error I get

Comment: `\def\r{3}` defines the `\r` variable to 3. If you want smaller or bigger triangles, you just have to change this value, instead of changing it inside every tikzpicture. Now for your error, I don't understand. On what platform do you compile? Is your TeX distribution up to date?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a part of the code that uses the Tikz calc library.

I'll let you look for the other figures.

PS: it would have been desirable that you show that you searched before asking the question.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) coordinate(A) --++(60:5cm) coordinate(B)--++(-60:5cm) coordinate(C)-- cycle;

\draw[red] (0,0) ($(A)!1/3!(B)$)coordinate(AB) -- ($(B)!2/3!(C)$)coordinate(BC) -- ($(C)!1/3!(A)$)-- ($(BC)!1/2!(AB)$)
-- ($(A)!1/3!(C)$) -- (AB);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I actually spent quite a while researching trying to figure this out. I really don't know how to use tikz at all and tried to transfer from geogebra to tikz. That's why I asked here. If you have any advice on how to learn tikz, that would be great!!

Comment: You can take a look at the [PGF manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) which teaches you how to use TikZ. Don't be afraid by the 1300+ pages, what you need to look at to learn are the tutorials at the beginning of the manual which are very well written and will teach you a lot of things on how to actually do things with TIkZ.

Answer (score 3):

A `pstricks` solution – more specifically, with `pst-eucl` (which mimicks geometric transformations) for the first figure. The second and third figures can be done similarly.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pst-eucl}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(0,4.5)(4.5,3)
    \psset{linejoin=1, HomCoef=0.667}
    \psset{PointSymbol=none, PointName=none}
    \pstTriangle(3;60){A}(0,0){B}(3,0){C}
    \pnodes(1;60){D}(1,0){E}(2,0){G}
    \pstHomO{A}{C}[H]
    \pstMiddleAB{D}{H}{F}
    \psline(D)(E)(F)(G)(H)(D)
    \end{pspicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!!

Comment: Can you explain why it gives me this error? I'm using overleaf:

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. 
\c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks 
                         _Not_Configured_For_This_Format
l.201     \pstTriangle(3;60){A}(0,0){B}(3,0){C}
                                               
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: To compile a document using PSTricks, you cannot use the `pdflatex` compiler. You have to either use a `latex` -> `ps` -> `pdf` chain or use `xelatex` or `lualatex`. To do so in Overleaf, go into your document's menu in the top left corner, and in compiler, change pdfLatex to either LaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX.